# How to create minimal Akka actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

An instantiation of 1 million Akka actors took ~20 seconds on my notebook: http://goo.gl/OwQht

Where should I dig to speed up creation of them, in the [configuration](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/73f24e9c2c04ba99481a297e95049e78f5a5292a/src/test/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/actors/AkkaActorSpec.scala#L14) or in the [code](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/73f24e9c2c04ba99481a297e95049e78f5a5292a/src/test/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/actors/AkkaActorSpec.scala#L106)?

Comment: First turn on verbose GC logging to see if that is the issue.

Comment: You want to create an `Actor` instance in substantially less than 20 microseconds?

Comment: Another question would be what do you need 1M actors for?

Comment: How does your actor hierarchy look? Are these all toplevel actors of the same ActorSystem? That might be a performance bottleneck. Try creating a hierarchy with 1000 toplevel actors, each having 1000 children. Also, it might be a good idea to give them names so the actor system does not have to generate unique names for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a little benchmark that shows how to create actors in a hierarchy. I also get about 20 seconds for ~1000000 actors, but this is on a pretty slow notebook CPU and no tweaking of JVM options like useNUMA that you have in your benchmark.

I tried to run your benchmark from github, and it wouldn't even start on my machine since it requires more than the 4GB of memory I have. So it seems that your notebook is way more powerful than mine.

Here is what I get when I create actors in a two level hierarchy (1000 groups of 1000 workers each)

```
Created 1001001 actors
20.752500989 s
48235.198279503136 actors per second
```

Here is what I get when I create 1000000 actors directly below the root actor:

```
Created 1000001 actors
56.118988558 s
17819.29834616461 actors per second
```

So clearly there is a large performance benefit in creating actors in a hierarchy even on a relatively slow machine like mine. On a machine with more cores the difference will be even larger.

Edit: I now ran the test on my main development machine, which is an i7 with 4 cores and thus significantly faster:

Two level hierarchy:

```
Created 1001001 actors
2.358266323 s
424464.78170735424 actors per second
```

Flat hierarchy

```
Created 1000001 actors
6.032559898 s
165767.27241971265 actors per second
```

Try to run this and report what you get. You can experiment with different hierarchy depths to see if it makes a difference. Make sure to add your CPU and system specs.

```
case class CreateChildren(n:Int, inner:Option[CreateChildren] = None)

class TestActor extends Actor {

  Main.newActorCreated()

  def receive = {
    case CreateChildren(n, inner) =>
      val children = (0 until n).map(i => context.actorOf(Props[TestActor], "child_"+i))
      for(msg<-inner; child<-children)
        child ! msg
  }
}

object Main extends App {

  val count = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger(0)

  val system = ActorSystem.create("test")
  val root = system.actorOf(Props[TestActor])
  val t0 = System.nanoTime()
  root ! CreateChildren(1000, Some(CreateChildren(1000)))
  val total = 1001001

  def newActorCreated() {
    if(Main.count.incrementAndGet()==total) {
      val dt = (System.nanoTime() - t0)/1e9
      val per = total/dt
      println(s"Created $total actors")
      println(s"$dt s")
      println(s"$per actors per second")
      system.shutdown()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating top level actors a performance penalty, so it definitely makes sense to introduce at least on level in the hierarchy (it is also good practice).

Comment: @endre-varga Is it explained in docs with examples? If this is the best practice, then why it is not done by the actor system by default?

Comment: Best practice is to organize your actors in a hierarchy, not a flat structure. It cannot be done by the actor system by default, since the "best" hierarchy is application dependent (it is a design decision).